# How to compare reverse strings in list of strings with the original list of strings in python?

Tags: python

Input a given string and check if any word in that string matches with its reverse in the same string then print that word else print $

I split the string and put the words in a list and then I reversed the words in that list. After that, I couldn't able to compare both the lists.

```
str = input()
x = str.split()
for i in x: # printing i shows the words in the list
    str1 = i[::-1] # printing str1 shows the reverse of words in a new list
    # now how to check if any word of the new list matches to any word of the old list 
    if(i==str):
        print(i)
        break
    else:
        print('$)
```

Input: `suman is a si boy`.

Output: `is` ( since reverse of 'is' is present in the same string)

Comment: You have a missing quote on the `print` line.

Comment: You're not checking against all the words in the string, you're just checking whether the word is the same as its own reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, just need to add another loop to compare each word against each inverted word. Try using the following

```
str = input()
x = str.split()
for i in x:
    str1 = i[::-1]
    for j in x: # <-- this is the new nested loop you are missing
        if j == str1: # compare each inverted word against each regular word
            if len(str1) > 1: # Potential condition if you would like to not include single letter words
                print(i)
```

---

Update

To only print the first occurrence of a match, you could, in the second loop, only check the elements that come after. We can do this by keeping track of the index:

```
str = input()
x = str.split()
for index, i in enumerate(x):
    str1 = i[::-1]
    for j in x[index+1:]: # <-- only consider words that are ahead
        if j == str1: 
            if len(str1) > 1: 
                print(i)
```

Note that I used `index+1` in order to not consider single word palindromes a match.

Comment: this code works but if we will put an else condition to print a $, by default it is printing the $ too after the first iteration. How to resolve that and we only have to print that word whose reverse occurs in its left side of the string. So the output should onyl come is... I tried doing it but didn't able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'suman is a si boy'

# Construct the list of words
words = a.split(' ')

# Construct the list of reversed words
reversed_words = [word[::-1] for word in words]

# Get an intersection of these lists converted to sets
print(set(words) & set(reversed_words))
```

will print:

> `{'si', 'is', 'a'}`

Comment: `reversed_words = {word[::-1] for word in words}` and `print(reversed_words.intersection(words))` avoids a needless list and two list to set conversion (set.intersection(iterable)) can handle lists.

Comment: See this code prints all the strings even those whose length is more than 1. And subsequently, it will always print the reverse of the word too. we don't want that. The output should only come (is) not it's reverse or not any single letter word

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is just in a list comprehension:

```
string = 'suman is a si boy'  

output = [x for x in string.split() if x[::-1] in string.split()]

print(output)
```

The split on string creates a list split on spaces. Then the word is included only if the reverse is in the string.

Output is:

```
['is', 'a', 'si']
```

One note, you have a variable name `str`.  Best not to do that as `str` is a Python thing and could cause other issues in your code later on.

If you want word more than one letter long then you can do:

```
string = 'suman is a si boy'

output = [x for x in string.split() if x[::-1] in string.split() and len(x) > 1]

print(output)
```

this gives:

```
['is', 'si']
```

**Final Answer...**

And for the final thought, in order to get just the `'is'`:

```
string = 'suman is a si boy'

seen = []
output = [x for x in string.split() if x[::-1] not in seen and not seen.append(x) and x[::-1] in string.split() and len(x) > 1]                      

print(output)
```

output is:

```
['is']
```

**BUT**, this is not necessarily a good way to do it, I don't believe. Basically you are storing information in `seen` *during* the list comprehension AND referencing that same list. :)

Comment: `x[::-1] == string` i think

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Umm... I don't think so. I want to see if the reverse of the word `x[::-1]` is *in* the original string.  I don't want to see if the reverse of the word *is* the whole string. Or am I not understanding the original?

Comment: sorry i misread and my idea was wrong- but i'm still not sure- you think they want `'is sit'` to return `'is'`

Comment: @Chris_Rands, oh, good point. lol.  I just added a `.split()`. :)

Comment: This code works well but we only need to print the string whose reverse is present in the string not the vice versa and only any single letter string.

Comment: @SumanSekharSarangi I added a a condition for string length.  I am confused by the second part of the thought.  The reverse of `is` and `si` are both in there.  So, do you want the *first* of each pair?

Comment: @SumanSekharSarangi, added one more to the answer where only "is" is listed -- all using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

This answer wouldn't show you 'a' and won't output 'is' with 'si'.

```
str = input() #get input string
x = str.split() #returns list of words
y = [] #list of words
while len(x) > 0 :
    a = x.pop(0) #removes first item from list and returns it, then assigns it to a
    if a[::-1] in x: #checks if the reversed word is in the list of words
                     #the list doesn't contain that word anymore so 'a' that doesn't show twice wouldn't be returned
                     #and 'is' that is present with 'si' will be evaluated once

        y.append(a)

print(y) # ['is']
```

Comment: Would you please explain the last three lines of the code? This code works correctly but the output is displayed as a list. How to resolve that. I mean output should come only (is) ??